# Get Threads Twitter API V2

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to use Twitter API to retrieve threads by the main tweet ID, but it seems like there is no endpoint to achieve this, so is there a way to work around with this to make it work? I have also tried to use search/recent and passing the conversation_id by it returns the comments, not the thread tweets.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use :

from:{user_id} to:{user_id} conversation_id:{tweet_id}

This will fetch the tweets following the initial tweet of the thread that are sent from the user_id (=author_id) to the user_id. => All the tweets of the thread.

Answer (score 0):

The @Robin's solution sometimes returns extra tweets(a series of replies by the author to someone's reply). Using this search query param:

`?query=conversation_id:{conversation_id} from:{author_id} to:{author_id}&tweet.fields=author_id,referenced_tweets`

you can get `referenced_tweets` data which helps you to reconstruct the thread.
[Check this sample code](https://gist.github.com/0xNima/48f6244508611e71c56ce156bc2ef4fd)